# Android detect if user stopped moving

Tags: android, gps

I am working on an Android app, which warns the user if he has not been moving for a fixed period of time. 
I wanted to determine if the user moves by comparing the GPS positions every few seconds.
Since I have however heard that the GPS positions are very inaccurate and can vary greatly, I was wondering what the best way would be to determine if the user does not move?

Comment: Look, Daddy: another battery drainer! Fantasic!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at using activity recognition.  You can get more information about it here:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

Comment: you forget to add that to get such status from that API you may need to wait 10-50 seconds, it's not real time at all!

Comment: Hi @user924, I'm looking to implement something similar. Do you know any better (more real-time) solution?

Answer (score 3):

I would think using the accelerometer would be a fairly good way of determining if they had been moving.

Comment: The accelerometer only covers acceleration, not velocity. Someone holding their phone steadily enough while moving would cause it to think they're not moving, and a person not moving but shakily holding their phone would set it off easily.

While this is not exactly finding movement, it will probably work for OP's purposes.

Comment: Hi @AaronFranke , I'm looking to implement something similar. Any idea how can I try to make it work? –